# Push items in an array after ajax postback

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, ajax

I've this script on my *.cshtml* page

```
$(function () {
        var tempArray = [];
        var tbValue = $('#tb1').val();
        $.ajax({
            url: "/ControllerName/getdata",
            dataType: 'json',
            data: { strText: tbValue },
            success: function (Data) {
                $.each(Data, function (index, value) {
                    tempArray.push(value.Name);
                });

                $("#tb1").autocomplete({
                    source: tempArray,
                    minLength: 0
                });
            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                console.log(xhr.status);
                console.log(xhr.responseText);
                console.log(thrownError);
                alert("failure");
            }

        });

    });
```

Now after the ajax call i get a list of objects in `Data`, like this

[image]

I get the following values of `index` and `value` in each loop

[image]

[image]

The problem comes when i try to push data in the `tempArray` inside each loop.

[image]

I get undefined item in my array and it comes out of each loop. How can i add items in the array?

**Note:** There are no errors in console log and I'm working on MVC3.

Comment: What is the *actual* data received? *Include a relevant sample JSON* from the network monitor *as text* in the question (not an image). From the images and values reported it appears there is an *outer* wrapper array/object.

Comment: Also, move the tempArray *into* the success callback to increase code clarity (it serves no purpose outside) - assigning to or mutating a shared object is almost never correct in an AJAX handler and has led to many incorrect usages.

Comment: @user2864740: i get this value
`Data: Array[12]
0: Object
Class: 1
Id: 1
Name: "Amit "
Section: "A"`

and also tried taking `tempArray` in Success

Comment: @downvoters: comments plzz..?

Comment: That is not what was requested. Provide the ***actual example JSON, as text**, from the network monitor*.

Comment: @user2864740: I'm not getting what exactly you are trying to say.. plz throw some light on it... what do you want, the code how i'm sending Data or what?

Comment: Well, I downvoted and voted to close - this is why. The "problem" would be trivially fixed if *looking at and reporting the actual JSON server response*, as requested. The question is a simple bug in the code and is a localized problem wasting time. The JSON you are receiving looks like `{"Data": stuff_here}`. Have a good day.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this.

```
$.each(Data.Data, function (index, value) {
    tempArray.push(value.Name);
});
```

Your Ajax return variable "Data" is Object

```
Data = {Data:[array maybe has 12 size]}
```